# sshfs too slow while remote editing on Eclipse and other IDEs, what options to use to make it faster. *Not* for mac users

Tags: linux, ssh, eclipse, sshfs

I've been looking into this problem, and it is common. But since there is a package for Mac with the same name, the solution for Mac users is hiding the solution for Linux users and our default sshfs.

This the best I got so far, from what actually works on Linux.

sshfs user@host:remoteDir localDir -o Ciphers=arcfour -oauto_cache,reconnect,no_readahead

note: this question was not appropriate for stackoverflow, dunno why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365487/sshfs-too-slow-what-options-to-use-to-make-it-faster-not-for-mac-users

Comment: How for away (hops/geographically) is the remote host?

Comment: This is a west-europe to ?-america thing. But I actually have an option to change it to europe to europe, that would be smart. You have any suggestions based on this?

Comment: Well, yes. You could test it locally and see if it’s fast enough. If it isn’t, `sshfs` is not the solution you’re looking for.

Comment: I was kinda looking for some comments on the sshfs parameters I used.

Comment: You can’t hide network (and protocol!) latency. Especially with SFTP/SCP, which do not push state changes to clients. It’s simply a terribly inefficient protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important option is compression, *-C*.

Answer (score 1):

My network drives are painfully slow at work, so I made a CRON job which executes `rsync -triv --delete` to periodically synchronize the files in the background.  You should time the rsync job a few times to determine a suitable interval so that you don't end up with multiple rsyncs piling up trying to copy at the same time.

If you have to have up-to-the-second changes propagated, this won't work for you.

Comment: I thought about using rsync somehow, but it was kind of like this: As I'm working on a big eclipse remote project, make a partial local copy of the part I'm working on. Close remote project. Work on partial local project. Rsync when you are done. Open remote project to check it again. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: I would only do that if the project was so big that I couldn't make a local copy of the entire thing.  You definately don't want to be calling `--delete` if you only have a partial copy, and if you don't call that, then if you ever need to delete a file, you'll have to delete files manually on the remote copy too.  That's too manual for my tastes, which is why I keep everything locally and rely on `rsync` to not copy unchanged stuff back and forth.

Comment: It is in fact a huge folder, and it's a live folder, as in, it is being run by the remote systme as I edit it (the whole reason I'm doing it like this). Having a remote project and a local clone of it on which you edit and then resync with the remote, is a weird solution, but I guess it can work.